# Restructure FB.login javascript code to get a response from asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, asynchronous

I am using Facebook Javascript SDK with a custom login button:

```
<button id="login" onclick="javascript:login();">Login Facebook</button>
```

and javascript function is:

```
function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {

    // handle the response

        FB.api('/me', { locale: 'en_US', fields: 'name, email' },
            function(response) {
                email = response.email;
                name = response.name;
            }
        );

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                console.log('Response goes here! ' + email + ' of ' + name + ' of ' + user_id);

                    $.ajax({
                            url: "includes/ajax_fb.php",
                            data:{email:email,name:name,user_id:user_id},
                            type: "POST",
                            success:function (data) {
                                    if(!data.error) {
                                            // location.reload(true);
                                            $("#ajax-response").html(data);
                                    }
                            }
                    });

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                alert(response.status);

            } else {
                alert(response.status);

            }
        });

    }, {scope: 'public_profile,email'});
}
```

When I press login button once I am connected but no `console.log` and no data in `#ajax-response` are shown.

When I press login button for second time, `console.log` and data in `#ajax-response` are shown in console.

After the second button press, `console.log` and data in `#ajax-response` are shown with each consecutive button press.

I was pointed to [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for a solution, and after thoroughly examining it, I understand I need to restructure my code to "Let functions accept callbacks". I've been trying to get it to work for hours now, and still cant figure it out :(

How do I restructure my code to make `console.log` and data in `#ajax-response` to show on the very first button press?

Comment: By handling that data inside the callback function. (If you are not aware that the above code is making use of callback functions already, then you should perhaps go look up what those actually are a little more thoroughly.)